# How do I generate a sine wave using Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, waveform, trigonometry

I'm trying to generate a sine wave of a given frequency for a given duration and then write it into a .wav file. I'm using numpy's sin function and scipy's wavfile function. I'm getting a weird sound that is definitely not a sine wave.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavfile

fs = 44100

f = int(raw_input("Enter fundamental frequency: "))
t = float(raw_input("Enter duration of signal (in seconds): "))

samples = np.arange(t * fs)

signal = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * samples)

signal *= 32767

signal = np.int16(signal)

wavfile.write(str(raw_input("Name your audio: ")), fs, signal)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Have I made some fundamentally incorrect assumption about sine waves or something?

Comment: What happens if you try `samples = np.arange(t * fs) / fs`?

Answer (score 19):

Change

```
samples = np.arange(t * fs)
```

to

```
samples = np.linspace(0, t, int(fs*t), endpoint=False)
```

(This assumes that `fs*t` results in an integer value.)

Or, as Paul Panzer suggests in a comment,

```
samples = np.arange(t * fs) / fs
```

Your `samples` was just the sequence of integers 0, 1, 2, ... `fs*t`.  Instead, you need the actual time values (in seconds) of the samples.

Comment: I think mine is marginally more precise (in case `fs*t` is not integer).

Comment: Yeah, now I understand! The samples variable has to be in seconds and not samples. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

A simplified approach:

```py
cycles = 2 # how many sine cycles
resolution = 25 # how many datapoints to generate

length = np.pi * 2 * cycles
my_wave = np.sin(np.arange(0, length, length / resolution))
```

Generates:

```py
[ 0.      0.4818  0.8443  0.998   0.9048  0.5878  0.1253 -0.3681 -0.7705
 -0.9823 -0.9511 -0.6845 -0.2487  0.2487  0.6845  0.9511  0.9823  0.7705
  0.3681 -0.1253 -0.5878 -0.9048 -0.998  -0.8443 -0.4818]
```

[image: generated_sine_wave]

---

*Note: Leaving this answer here despite not addressing sine wave for audio generation, since I found that for my application it was more intuitive to only parameterise length of the wave and number of datapoints generated, as opposed to fundamental frequency and duration in seconds.*

Answer (score 4):

Use this and set the parameters as you want

```
start_time = 0
end_time = 1
sample_rate = 1000
time = np.arange(start_time, end_time, 1/sample_rate)
theta = 0
frequency = 100
amplitude = 1
sinewave = amplitude * np.sin(2 * np.pi * frequency * time + theta)
figure(figsize=(20, 6), dpi=80)
plt.plot(sinewave)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing sample value and length! Try:

```
samples = np.linspace(0, t, t * fs)
```

Another detail: you don't need the `str` around `raw_input`.