# Python Sine wave outputting random sounds

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, pygame, synthesizer

I am trying to build a python synthesizer using pygame.

I followed some tutorials and combined some code from different sources, but when playing the output as a sound, I get random noise for different frequencies.

Here is the code with irrelevant parts ommitted:

```
import key_manager as km
from array import array 
import pygame
from pygame import mixer
from pygame.mixer import Sound, get_init,  pre_init
import time
import numpy as np
import math

class Note(pygame.mixer.Sound): 

    def __init__(self, frequency, volume=.1): 
        self.frequency = frequency 
        if synth_type == "sine":
            Sound.__init__(self, self.build_samples_sine()) 
        self.set_volume(volume) 

    def build_samples_sine(self): 
        period = int(round(get_init()[0] / self.frequency)) 
        samples = array("h", [0] * period * 2) 
        amplitude = 2 ** (abs(get_init()[1]) - 1) - 1 
        for time in range(period * 2): 
            samples[time] = int(round(amplitude * math.sin(2 * math.pi * self.frequency * time)))
        return samples

pre_init(44100, -16, 1, 1024)
pygame.init()
frequency = <whatever frequency I am trying to play>
mixer.Channel(frequency).play(note, -1)
```

Thanks for any help or advice.

Comment: I'm not sure you're generating samples correctly. All the flooring and rounding doesn't make much sense to me. Check this out for  example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48043004/how-do-i-generate-a-sine-wave-using-python

Comment: I tried following some of the advice in the example, but it didn't seem to fix my problem. Also the rounding was unnecessary.

Comment: Can you explain what "random noise" you're referring to? Is it the same sound being played regardless of the frequency you select? Can you use your phone or some other device to measure the frequency of the output?

Comment: Here you're doing `period = int(round(get_init()[0] / self.frequency)) ` . Why are you calling `get_init()`? This simply returns you the default frequency. Why aren't you just constructing the wave and samples directly from your input?

Comment: The random noise sounds like a really rough sine wave, but at the wrong frequencies, for example, A4 is lower than H4 and B4 is an array of just zeros.

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63980631/2280890)?

Comment: Watch out for your `time` calculation. With `time` your are stepping over samples, but if you want to increase phase you want to step over time. I think it should be `samples[time] = int(round(amplitude * math.sin(2 * math.pi * self.frequency * time / sampling_rate)))` where `sampling_rate` is `44100.0`. You also probably want to use `math.trunc`  `samples[time] = int(math.trunc(amplitude * math.sin(2 * math.pi * self.frequency * time / sampling_rate)))`

Comment: Additionally, while predefining a buffer of two phases of a sine wave is "fine", I can foresee a problem with mismatches in buffer size. You probably want to implement a phasor (linear ramp from 0.0 - 1.0) that drives the phase of a sine function. That way you can simply fill each new buffer on the fly. It will also give you the ability to vary the frequency without relying on buffer size.